# React.FC generic one of

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to build component that will either return a router Link or provide a Button depending on props.
Here's my piece of code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

type OwnProps = { url: string } | { onClick: () => void };

const NavButton: React.FC<OwnProps> = ({ url, onClick, children }) => (
  <Button component={url ? Link : undefined} to={url} onClick={onClick}>
    {children}
  </Button>
);

export default NavButton;
```

However, I get an error saying:

> TS2339: Property 'url' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren '.

> TS2339: Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren '.

P.S.: I don't want both props to be included in the interface. I want either this or that.

Comment: @rid at this point return value doesn't matter because it doesn't allow me to use those props at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can type `OwnProps` like this:

```
{ url: string, onClick?: never } | { url?: never, onClick: () => void }
```

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about never types 